# C - string to uint64_t casting with error handling

Tags: c, error-handling, string-parsing

This program is to cast strings to `uint64_t` types and get the errors if any.

It should output, in this case, 2 errors (overflow and negative number), none of which appear. Also, it doesn't properly cast one of the strings.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

int func(const char *buff) {
    char *end;
    int si;

    errno = 0;

    const uint64_t sl = strtoull(buff, &end, 10);

    if (end == buff) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: not a decimal number\n", buff);
    } else if ('\0' != *end) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: extra characters at end of input: %s\n", buff, end);
    } else if ((sl < 0 || ULONG_MAX == sl) && ERANGE == errno) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s out of range of type uint64_t\n", buff);
    } else if (sl > ULONG_MAX) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%ld greater than ULONG_MAX\n", sl);
    } else if (sl < 0) {
     fprintf(stderr, "%ld negative\n", sl);
    } else {
    si = (int)sl;
    }

    return si;
}

int main()
{

    printf("%d\n", func("123456789123465789"));
    printf("%d\n", func("123456789123465789123465789"));
    printf("%d\n", func("-1"));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us what output you get and what output you expect.

Comment: `sl < 0` not possible

Comment: ...and `si` may end up uninitialized.

Comment: ... and this program doesn't _cast_ anything but it _converts_.

Comment: Read: https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoull in order to see the correct way to use the function strtoull

Answer (score 0):

`strtoull();` allows input that begin with `'-'`.  The function converts the numeric portion of the text and then negates it, the result is still an *unsigned* integer.  So code cannot use the result of `strtoull()` to determine if the text represented a negative number as with `uint64_t sl;`, `sl < 0` is always false.

Code needs to detect the `'-'` in other ways.

I'd expect the function to return an `uint64_t`

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// int func(const char *buff) {
uint64_t func(const char *buff) {
  const char *s = buff;
  // consume leading whitespace
  while (isspace((unsigned char ) *s)) {
    s++;
  }
  int sign = *s;
  if (sign == '-' || sign == '+') {
    s++;
  }
  // Now code knows it the text is "negative"

  // rest of OP's code needs a some work
  char *end;
  errno = 0;
  unsigned long long sl = strtoull(s, &end, 10);

  if (end == s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: not a decimal number\n", buff);
  } else if ('\0' != *end) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: extra characters at end of input: %s\n", buff, end);
    // } else if ((sl < 0 || ULONG_MAX == sl) && ERANGE == errno) {
  } else if (sign == '-') {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s negative\n", buff);
    sl = 0;
    errno = ERANGE;
  } else if (ERANGE == errno) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s out of range of type uint64_t\n", buff);

    // Only needed on rare machines
#if ULLONG_MAX > UINT64_MAX
    else if (sl > UINT64_MAX) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s out of range of type uint64_t\n", buff);
      sl = UINT64_MAX;
      errno = ERANGE;
    }
#endif

  }
  return (uint64_t) sl;
}
```

OP's returning of an `int` is strange.  Leave updating `main()` to OP.