# How to check that inputed number is positive?

Tags: c, validation, io, numbers, unsigned-long-long-int

I need to read a positive number only (`unsigned long long`), a nothing is more, so I use `scanf("%llu", &num);`. But it also allows to input negative values.
How to validate positive numbers in this case? The user must input a positive number in **[0..2^(64)-1]** but he can miss and input a negative value in same interval. But I can't declare a `long long` variable to check it cuz it can contain **2^64 - 1** totally.

Comment: Read as a *string* (e.g. using `fgets()`) and do your validation on it.

Comment: Sorry, Imma noobie in C really... How can I convert a string to `unsigned long long` after?

Comment: See [string to uint64_t casting with error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46325780/2410359)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the input into a character array using `fgets()`, check if the first character is <s>`-`ve symbol</s> a character other than a digit and then use `strtoull()` to convert it to `unsigned long long`.

```
char c, buff[100];
fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin);
//sscanf(buff, "%*[ ]%c", &c);
sscanf(buff, "%s", buff);
//if( (c<'0' || c>'9') )
if(buff[0]<'0' || buff[0]>'9')
{
     printf("\nNegative or invalid number!");
}
else
{
     num=strtoull(buff, NULL, 10);
}
```

`strtoull()` will return `ULLONG_MAX` (defined in `limits.h`) and sets `errno` to `ERANGE`(to use these, `errno.h` header file must be included) if the value returned by it won't fit in an `unsigned long long`.

```
if(num==ULLONG_MAX && errno==ERANGE)
{
    printf("\nOverflow");
}
```

<s>The `%*[ ]` in the `sscanf()` is used to ignore the leading white spaces in the string.
The first non-space character is found and stored in `c` whose value is checked.</s>

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24168813/5375464), `sscanf(buff, "%s", buff);` would trim the string `buff` on both sides to get rid of the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Read the number as a string with [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), then validate it, e.g. with [`strchr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/). Finally use [`strtoull()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoull/) to convert the string to number, which will fail if the number is out range:

> If the value read is out of the range of representable values by an
>   unsigned long long int, the function returns ULLONG_MAX (defined in
>   `<limits.h>`), and `errno` is set to `ERANGE`.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[100]=;
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';

    if(strchr(str, '-') == NULL) {
        printf("Not a negative number\n");
        unsigned long long number = strtoull (str, NULL, 10);
        printf("%llu\n", number);
    } else {
        printf("Negative number\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Not a negative number
12343566
```

and for -12343566, it gives:

```
Negative number
```